# How can I create RBAP for Spring/React app?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an Admin Dashboard React Bootstrap Template and I want to create the backend for it.
I have built a separated REST API on a separate port using Spring that queries a Postgres DB. The frontend just fetches the API.
The problem is that I want to have different user roles: different Navbar items, different page content, etc. based on permissions/role.
I've tried using spring-security and it works when accessing API, but I don't know how to connect it to the front.
How can I implement RBAC for a separate React Front, Spring API Back web app?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security doesn't have any direct support for front-ends, though Spring does have a [few blog posts](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) that describe how a JavaScript front-end can coordinate with a Spring Security-protected back-end.

The key insight is a `/user` endpoint for transmitting the user's details to the front-end.